# ¿Cómo corregir este problema con proyecto ejecutado con ASP.NET en VisualStudio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, localhost

He ejecutado un proyecto ASP.NET en Visual Studio , pero no ha logrado ejecutarse, pues sale se muestra como un intento fallido de conexión al localhost espero puedan ayudarme adjuntare una imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor: añade información de lo que salga en los logs al ejecutarlo. Así mismo, procura evitar el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas. Gracias!

Comment: Saludos sr, no sale ningun error en el log :)